# Generalized additive model: low F-test?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, generalized-additive-model, f-test

I am confused about the F-test value in the smoothing terms of a GAM model.

```
Parametric coefficients:

             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.38633    0.19362   1.995   0.0524    
SexMale     -0.02751    0.12968  -0.212   0.8330  
Educ        -0.04892    0.03532  -1.385   0.1731
```

---

Approximate significance of smooth terms:

```
         edf    Ref.df    F  p-value   
s(Age)   0.8993      9 0.992 0.00254
s(crop)  0.7520      9 0.196 0.10911   
s(cor)   1.4810      9 0.356 0.11928   
R-sq.(adj) =  0.235   Deviance explained = 31.7%
-REML = 26.251  Scale est. = 0.12429   n = 49
```

---

How is it possible that the F-test for the smooth term of Age is below 1 and still so significant?

Here is the plot of the age effect (linear):
[image]

Interestingly, I ran a model with another outcome variable and there the F-test for s(age) was F=1.593 and p-value=0.00318 (this is a quadratic fit: going up and then down). Is a higher F-value associated with more curves in the fit?

Comment: It may be relevant to know what function in what package you called (since different implementations of GAM may well use different calculations for the tests and p-values)

Comment: This is certainly from mgcv. What do you see when you plot the spline of `Age`. It's likely it is either i) a shrunken but non-linear function and this non-linearity is evidence against the null hypothesis of $f(\text{Age})$ being a flat function, or ii) the function is linear but penalised and against inconsistent with a flat function. The p-value used here is for a test that's related to the frequentist across-the-function confidence interval for the spline & use some quite complex math I haven't really gotten my head around. But plot the smooth and that should explain why `s(Age)` is signif

Comment: Yes, this is mgcv, sorry for not mentioning this.
mgcv::gam(left~ s(Age,bs="cr")+Sex+Educ+s(crop,bs="cs")+s(cor,bs="cs"), data=data, method="REML", select=TRUE). The plot is linear, negative (will try to upload it)
I was trying to use the F-value to show the strength of the association between Y and age, but is that not a good measure? I think a higher F-value should still indicate a better fit?

Comment: You're using `select = TRUE`.  That penalizes the null space of the function, which is to say that it allows the "main effect" and not just the "smooth" component to be penalized.  While these aren't super-easy to distinguish in the complicated spline bases that `mgcv` uses, when `select = FALSE`, the OLS fit is always nested within the space of possible estimated functions.  This is no longer true when `select = TRUE` -- you're basically running something analogous to a ridge regression.  And given that ridge regression gives biased marginal effects, it isn't clear how to interpret p-values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Would GCV be better than REML/ML?

Comment: with respect to interpretation of the *p* values, Wood (2013, Biometrika) describes a Wald statistic for the test that $f_{j}(x) = 0$ using Nychka's arguments about the across-the-function frequentist interpretation of Bayesian credible intervals for the spline. I understand that this is what is reported as `F` in the table. From what I understand, this is not F-distributed; the distribution of the test statistic is complex involving contributions from several $\chi^2$ distributions owing to the non-integer EDF for a spline & whether or not the scale parameter is estimated or assumed known.

Comment: The detail is in [Wood (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/ass048) or in §6.12 of Wood (2017, 2nd Edition of his GAM book). As to whether GCV or REML/ML would be better; I understand that coverage is best with ML, followed by REML. I'm not sure if GCV was included in such tests, in part because GCV isn't available for all the families included in mgcv today.

To some extent, since you are using `select = TURE`, does it matter what the resulting p-values are? If you trust what the double penalties are doing, you can ignore the *p* value, can't you?